# How to choose the right background for an app?

Tags: design, background

I'm building a suggestion engine web application, it will be very minimal .

The users will need to fill a form to get the result, the form has around 7 to 8 inputs that must be filled . I already figure out how to keep the input UX smooth .

However I don't know which background type should I use : Image, Color , Simple Colored Patterns or just white .

My web app let the user interact and use it directly,it's UX is similar to google home page, but instead of one large text input (the search bar) . I do have multiple inputs .

So how can I chose the right background ? I'm also looking at a material design UI .

Comment: If you could post the different options we can discuss on them, because any of them could work correctly generally.

Comment: I think this is a good UX question, since - as I interpret it - it's about how different backgrounds affect UX (specifically, readability).

Comment: I don't think this questions is off topic for the reason given, but because it opinion based. There is no "correct" answer as a blank white screen can be just as usable all a full screen image in the right context. I do think this question to be reworded to, as Ken said, discuss the key points in different types of backgrounds and how they affect the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a UX Design perspective...

- Setting type on an image or pattern makes the text hard to read. The patterns interfere with the type shapes.
- Setting type on a color can be okay, if the contrast between background and text is high. [WCAG suggests](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#visual-audio-contrast) a contrast of 4.5:1. ([Here's a tool](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/) to tell you what the contrast is.)
- Setting dark text on white is best.

Personally, I don't see any reason to add visual complexity to an app that is "very minimal."